# How do I show a general scalar is Lorenz invarient?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

Let us say I have a general scalar $\alpha$ (e.g. mass, charge etc.) how would I show whether or not this is Lorentz Invariant?

I know that it can be shown easily when $\alpha=A^\mu B_\mu$ but I am interested to know about the case where no such expression can be formed (if such a case even exists?).

Comment: The definition of a scalar is that it is Lorentz invariant. If you want to prove that a specific quantity is a scalar, that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of quantum field theory all quantities are represented as irreducible representations of the Lorentz group (or more generally of the Poincare group). These representations come with different spins. Spin zero, which we call scalars, are singlets. They don't transform under the Lorentz transformation. Spin half, generally refers to as fermions, do transform under Lorentz transformations. Spin one, the vector bosons, also transform.

So as for a proof that scalars are invariant? I think it is immediate, based on the basic group theory that identifies scalars as the singlets under the Lorentz group.